# What is the recommended way to get nmap on OSX?

Tags: macos, nmap

Can I just use apt-get, or should I use some Mac tool?

Comment: By default there is no `apt-get` on OS X. So the question is, do you already have `apt-get` installed (probably by installing FINK) and now you are unsure if you can install `nmap` with it? Or are you completely unsure about how to install `nmap` or other such packages and just chose `apt-get` as an example?

Answer (score 76):

### First Option

***Nmap's Official Website***

- Download the latest official installer here:
  https://nmap.org/download.html#macosx
- Check this out for additional information:
  https://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html
- Alternative versions can be found here:
  https://nmap.org/dist/

---

### Second Option

***Homebrew Package Manager***

- Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

  ```
  $ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
  ```
- Install Nmap

  ```
  $ brew install nmap
  ```
- Optional

  ```
  $ brew search nmap
  $ brew info nmap
  ```

---

### Third Option

***MacPorts Package Manager***

- Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)

  ```
  $ bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tjt263/macports-installer/master/macports-installer.sh)"
  ```
- Install Nmap

  ```
  $ sudo port install nmap
  ```
- Optional

  ```
  $ sudo port search nmap
  $ sudo port info nmap
  ```

Comment: WARNING: this post gives commands to execute remote code on your machine! Do Not run anything from "raw.githubusercontent.com" as it can change and is not the official method.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky True for MacPorts, but for Homebrew that *is* the official way.

Comment: Third option is my favourite.

Comment: anyone concerned about executing code is expected to vet it first.

Answer (score 15):

The  package manager for MacOS that  apple mention https://developer.apple.com/opensource/  is MacPorts. And the nmap website mentions MacPorts.

A package manager that people often use with MacOS, is Homebrew. To install nmap, using Homebrew- http://brewformulas.org/Nmap  `brew install nmap`. Though another answer mentions that brew has an issue installing nmap as of 2020, and the nmap website mentions Macports and doesn't mention brew.

**Additional notes**
Your question is largely answered at this unix.stackexchange link.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/how-to-install-apt-get-or-yum-on-mac-os-x  So, apt-get is not really recommended as a package manager for MacOS, it's for Debian(so, e.g. Ubuntu is debian based hence Ubuntu uses apt-get). Homebrew is one for Mac OS.. and another one called macports. ..Apparently you can get apt-get on macOS but getting it to work is, they say here, a bit advanced.

I suggest you learn your package manager, e.g. in the case of MacOS, macports or homebrew, learn how to get a list of packages, or search for a package e.g. search for nmap, see the command to search or list packages and to install a package. (besides googling can show what package managers apply for your OS and then what command to install the package.. sometimes the programs website can mention it)

**added**

this link https://ports.macports.org/port/nmap/  mentions clearly how to install nmap with the MacPorts package manager `sudo port install nmap`

Installing nmap with MacPorts, or with the Fink package manager, are mentioned on the nmap site https://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html

Comment: It's a little bold to say "The package manager for MacOS is homebrew", it's just as official as Mac Ports.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky thanks, i've corrected my statement

Comment: Apple Inc. officially recognize and acknowledge MacPorts but not Homebrew: https://developer.apple.com/opensource/

Answer (score 2):

As of May 20, 2020, the homebrew installer fails to install something called nmap-scripts. This means nmap will work for some scans, but as you start to go deeper, you may see error messages like this:

```
nmap -p 1-65535 -T4 -A -v example.com
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-20 13:25 JST
Unable to find nmap-services!  Resorting to /etc/services
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
could not locate nse_main.lua
stack traceback:
    [C]: in ?

QUITTING!
```

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446898/nmap-could-not-locate-nse-main-lua) explains what is missing. Unfortunately that package is not available through homebrew at the moment.

The most foolproof way at the moment is to either use a different package manager (both fink and macports are endorsed by nmap.org), build it from source, or download the installer from nmap.org. All methods are explained [here.](https://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html)